# Absent choice, if $A$ and $B$ have a bijection, must every surjective function from $A$ to $B$ have a right inverse?

Tags: set-theory, axiom-of-choice

This question seems elementary and there's probably a really obvious argument for this that I'm not thinking of but I can't find it anywhere.

For equinumerous $A$, $B$, must *every* surjection $f:A \twoheadrightarrow B$ have a right inverse? What about if just $A = B$? If for some reason this *doesn't* apply in $ZF$ does it hold with something weaker than full choice like the partition principle or countable choice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. In fact even taking $A=B$ this is equivalent to the axiom of choice.

This is an observation made by Jech and myself a while ago when we talked about this sort of propositions.

The point is to take a function which has no injective inverse and use the domain and range to define a set and a self-surjection which has no inverse.

[You can find the details here.](http://karagila.org/2013/equivalent-to-the-axiom-of-choice-that-i-didnt-know-about/)

Comment: In your example infinitely many copies of $A$ are sent via $f$ onto $B$ and the other copies are mapped identically to cover the rest. Wouldn't it be a bit simpler to have just one copy of $A$ cover $B$ through $f$ and then shift everything else by one, i.e. $g(u, k+1) = (u, k)$ for $(u, k) \in A \times \omega$?

Comment: Yeah, could be. This can be improved, I guess.